# Why cant I pass a non const pointer to a function taking a reference to a pointer to a const as its argument

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Here's a code snippet that hopefully conveys what I'm trying to do:

```
void updatePointer(const int*& i)
{
  i++;
}

int main() {


  int array[5];
  int* arrayPtr = array;

  updatePointer(arrayPtr );
  return 0;
}
```

This gives compiler error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:16: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int*&’ from
expression of type ‘int*’
prog.cpp:5: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void updatePointer(const int*&)’
```

Comment: i think you cant get non-const reference to const at all

Comment: I decided to delete my answer because I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I'm basically asking why wont the above code compile

Comment: The question is clear, in the title. However, the example does not reflect the question... and the body of the function clearly violates what the OP wants to achieve. To be honest the question is formulated in a kind of stupid way. Even more, if you are asking why the code does not compile. If you corrected example to reflect your question it still would not compile due to a whole different matter. =)

Comment: I disagree - I want a function that can modify the pointer but not what it points to.

Comment: Well after edit it's a quite a different question I would say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing that you could do it, you could write the following:

```
const int c = 0;

void updatePointer(const int* &i) {
    i = &c;
}

int main() {
    int *ptr;
    updatePointer(ptr);
    *ptr = 1; // attempt to modify the const object c, undefined behavior
}
```

The purpose of `const` is to ensure that user code cannot attempt to modify a const object unless it contains a const-cast (or equivalent). So the compiler has to refuse this code. Forbidding a `const int*&` from binding to an `int*` is the only place in the code above that's reasonable for the compiler to refuse: every other line is fine.

It's the same reason you can't implicitly convert `int**` to `const int **`.

Aside from the motivation in terms of const-safety, you can think if it in terms of `int*` being a different type from `const int*`, that just so happens to be convertible to it. Likewise, you can convert `int` to `double`, but a `double&` can't bind to an `int` lvalue. That's not the full reason, because actually `int*` and `const int*` have the same size and representation, whereas `int` and `double` don't. So there could be a special-case to allow it if not for the fact that it would break the const system.

The reason that C++ has both const and non-const overloads for `strchr` is related to this issue: your function `updatePointer` modifies its input rather than returning the updated value, but the principle is similar. The C-style single `strchr` allows you to "launder" a pointer-to-const into a pointer-to-non-const without a cast, and it's a hole in the const system. C++ (a) has overloading and (b) has a stricter type system than C, so it closes that hole.

If you want your real function `updatePointer` to work like `strchr` -- examine the data pointed to and compute a new value for the pointer, then you're in the same situation that `strchr` is. That's regardless of what it does with the new value (return it in the case of `strchr`, write it back in the case of `updatePointer`), because the issue is that you want the new pointer to have the same const-qualification as the input. You need to provide either const- and non-const overloads or a function template.

If you only need your real function `updatePointer` to move a pointer by a certain distance, regardless of the data pointed to, you could use `std::advance` instead.

Answer (score 5):

What you wrote is a function taking a reference to a pointer to a const int. What you're asking for would be

```
updatePointer(int* const & i);
```

However this doesn't make much sense. Passing a reference to a pointer seems to imply that you intend to modify the pointer, but you cannot do it because it is declared const. As it is you'd obtain the same effect by just passing your pointer as in

```
updatePointer(int* i);
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the question title and didn't get a chance to update before you posted this

Answer (score 1):

[Found this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?470209-Initialization-of-constant-pointer-reference-member-variable)
Copied here in case the link breaks in future:

The reasoning is a little awkward to comes to grips with. The main question is:
Since a "const int&" can be bound to an "int", why can't a "const int*&" be bound to a "int*"?

Basically, once you add a level of indirection (a pointer) then the rules change. With just a single level of indirection (as in a single *), the rule can be stated as:

A reference to a pointer to a cv-qualified type can be bound to anything of that same type whose cv-qualifications are less than or equal to that of the pointer (which is a reference). 
(Read that a few times.)

So the reason a "const int*&" can't be bound to a "int*" is because "const int*" and "int*" are two different types (underlined part of the rule is broken).