# Compilation Error: const int *& reference = pointer_to_int. Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I tried to pass an argument of type `int*` to a function parameter of type const     `int*&` to avoid possible value alteration. As I stated in the question it doesn't work.
I suppose the reference considers `int*` and `const int*` two incompatible types but I wonder why.

I tried to set the reference as a `const int*const&` and it works although it is not what I need. 
The code I'm writing is a simple function to **swap** two pointers to int.

```
void swap(const int *&item1, const int *&item2)
{
const int *temp = item1;
item1 = item2;
item2 = temp;
}
```

For what I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong) a **reference to const** initialized with an object of incompatible (but convertible) type should generate a temporary object of the compatible type, initialize it with the **converted** incompatible object and finally bind the reference to that object. 
**E.g.**

```
int number = 10; const double &ref = number;
```

should be equivalent to:

```
int number = 10; const double temp = number; const double &ref = temp;
```

In this case `&ref != &number` but when I tried `int *ptr = nullptr; const int*const &ref = ptr;` `&ptr` and `&ref` were the same.

Comment: That's not a reference to const.  And no, binding to an lvalue won't create a reference.

Comment: `double &ref = number;` makes it refer to `number`. `double &ref = temp;` makes it refer to a different variable which is not referring to `number`. They are not equivalent at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cant I pass a non const pointer to a function taking a reference to a pointer to a const as its argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600094/why-cant-i-pass-a-non-const-pointer-to-a-function-taking-a-reference-to-a-pointe)

Comment: @chris: No, `int number; double& ref = number;` is a compile error, except in Visual C++, where as an extension it creates a temporary as he describes.  `int number; const double& ref = number;` is legal C++, and creates a temporary.

Comment: sorry... I wrote it wrong

Comment: @BenVoigt, Wow, I didn't even notice the types were different. I'm pretty sure that part was somewhat different before, but that makes only the latter legal, although not equivalent even with the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int*` and `const int*` **are** incompatible.  A value of type `int*` implicitly converts to a value of type `const int*`, but you can't use an `int*` variable as if it were a `const int*` variable (you can't store the address of a `const int`, which a real `const int*` would allow) and you can't use a `const int*` variable as if it were an `int*` (you can't write to the target, which a real `int*` would allow).