# Incompatible const pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Passing a non-const pointer to a function which expects a const pointer usually raises no warning (makes sense, the function promises to be "nicer" than the caller would expect), but a non-const pointer-to-pointer to a function expecting an const pointer-to-pointer does raise a warning (with `gcc -Wall`, 11.4) and I'm struggling to think why

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(const int *i)
{
  return *i;
}

int bar(const int **i)
{
  return **i;
}

int main(void)
{
  int i = 3, *pi = &i, **ppi = &pi;

  printf("foo: %i\n", foo(pi));
  printf("bar: %i\n", bar(ppi));

  return 0;
}
```

giving

```
$ gcc -Wall -o const const.c
const.c: In function ‘main’:
const.c:18:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘bar’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   18 |   printf("bar: %i\n", bar(ppi));
      |                           ^~~
      |                           |
      |                           int **
const.c:8:21: note: expected ‘const int **’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
    8 | int bar(const int **i)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
$ ./const 
foo: 3
bar: 3
```

Any enlightenment as to why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why cant I pass a non const pointer to a function taking a reference to a pointer to a const as its argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600094/why-cant-i-pass-a-non-const-pointer-to-a-function-taking-a-reference-to-a-pointe). Same issue applies, just swap the reference with a pointer.

Comment: TL;DR: it would be possible for `bar` to make `pi` point to a constant object. Just put `*i = &<constant>` in it's body. Then try to write to `*pi` in `main` - nasal demons will ensue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is given in the C standard. The following code is from C 2018 6.5.16.1 6. The comments are mine.

Given these declarations:

```
const char **cpp;
char *p;
const char c = ’A’;
```

Suppose we allowed assigning (by function call or direct assignment) a `char **` to a `const char **`, as in:

```
cpp = &p;
```

Then, since `*cpp` is a `const char *`, we can assign it a `const char *`, as in:

```
*cpp = &c;
```

Since `cpp` points to `p`, `*cpp = &c` changes `p` to point to `c`. And `*p` is nominally a `char`, we can assign a value to that `char`:

```
*p = 0;
```

That changes `c`, which is defined with `const`. So this cannot be allowed. The assignment `cpp = &p` is prohibited so this does not occur.

Comment: All becomes clear, many thanks.

Comment: You might want to add that one could use a `const int* const*` as argument type of `bar()`.

Comment: @Joel: That still will not let them pass their `ppi`, nor could they declare `ppi` as `const int * const *` and initialize it with `&pi`. For a fix, they would need to change the declaration of `pi`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil They dont need to make their `ppi` as `const int* const*`, just the argument `i` for `bar()`. Compiled just fine for me with msvc, however clang and gcc reported a warning for it,  but isnt it safe since you cant write to `*i` nor `**i`?

Comment: @Joel: I do not know what you are proposing. You cannot just change `i` because you need an intermediary like `pi` to pass to `bar`, since you cannot pass `& &i`. So you would have to change `pi` too. And we do not know that OP wants to change their `i`. When we have, say, a `char foo[]` that we are working with, we need to be able to pass it to a `const char *` parameter without changing the array to be `const char foo[]`, since that would prevent us from working with it. Similarly, changing `i` to const int i` takes an ability away from us.

Comment: @Joel: Re “Compiled just fine for me with msvc”: I do not know what source code you compiled, since “just the argument `i` for `bar()`” does not make sense.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just the code he posted, with the changed argument type for `bar()` [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/sEbe4PqGf)

Comment: @Joel: MSVC is not a C compiler. It is a C++ compiler with some C features. C++ has different rules and allows assignment of `int **` to `const int * const *`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it will make it clearer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(const int *i)
{
  return *i;
}

int bar(const int **i)
{
  return **i;
}

int main(void)
{
  int i = 3;
  const int *pi = &i; 
  const int **ppi = &pi;

  printf("foo: %i\n", foo(pi));
  printf("bar: %i\n", bar(ppi));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `const` pointer normally states that the pointed value is not modifiable, so the compiler will raise an error if you try to modify the data pointed to.  But if you alias a `const` pointer by assigning it to a non-`const` variable (as in parameter passing or an assignment statement), then the aliased pointer will no longer be protected by the compiler and it will allow you to modify the pointed data through the new non-`const` pointer value.

Some times, this is exactly what we want, but in that case, you can state it explicitly by making a cast to a non-`const` pointer type in the parameter passing code or the variable assignment and this will actually state your real intentions. Due to how dangerous that is to allow this kind of assignment, a warning is issued by default by the compiler (the warning can be avoided as told before, or just disabling the warning with a compilation option)

Comment: I get that passing a `const TYPE*` variable as argument to a `TYPE*` function raises a warning, I don't want it modifying but the function might do.  My bafflement is (was) the exact opposite, passing a `TYPE*` variable to a `const TYPE*` function raises a warning, at least in the case that `TYPE` is an `int*`

Comment: The problem is that you have a `const` pointer type and you want to use a function that doesn't admit a `const` pointer, so you have to convert it to non-`const` and pass it to a function that is supposed to modify the pointer referred contents, that''s a mesh!!!! But if you cannot do otherwise (as it happens with the illustrated example on `free()`) just convert it in the call calling `my_function((TYPE *) my_const_pointer, ...)` instead.  The example you showed required a `const` pointer because (as I understood) you sometimes return the original pointer (which is `const`) so you should...

Comment: ... never use that function to obtain a non-`const` pointer type.  That's incorrect use of the `const` feature.  You should only do it on purpose (as a means of converting a non-`const` to `const`) but never as some kind of side effect.  That's bad design.

Comment: Please look at the question again, my problem is not that "you have a const pointer type and you want to use a function that doesn't admit a const pointer" but the exact opposite: I have a non-const pointer I want to pass to a function which takes a const pointer.

Comment: The problem is _only_ with the second case, in which you have two incompatible referenced types, `const int *` is not compatible with `int *`, so the pointers to those different types are not compatible.   Just try it with `int bar(int * const *i);` and you will see how the non-`const` pointer is converted to a const pointer (in this case the pointed value is a non-`const` integer pointer converted to a `const` integer pointer.